# How to exit when Bash have an expression error, like [: -ne: unary operator expected

Tags: bash, error-handling

My experiences are with more recent (decent) languages. I'm used to have try/catch at my disposal.

I'm obligated by my client to use Bash.

I have a script which will do something very risky, but the first part of the script is about validating that everything is as expected before we run the risky procedure. During that validation phase, I want that if anything is wrong, it exit right away.

So I use:

```
set -e -u -o pipefail
set -o errtrace
```

But, the script still continue after it generate error like:

```
[: -ne: unary operator expected
```

It continue executing the script, and start the risky procedure even if the validation failed!

How can I detect error of that kind in Bash while executing?

Comment: Did you try `-n ... Read commands but do not execute them. This may be used to check a shell script for syntax errors. This is ignored by interactive shells.` from the `set` section of `man bash`. Good luck.

Comment: The syntax error is with variable expansion in some cases, also that code will not be reached if previous command doesn't execute.

Comment: well if you mean variable expansion as in `myVar="string with spaces" ; if [[ $myVar == 'string with spaces' ]]` then you need to read thru http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info . Remembering to  dbl-quote variables is in the top 5 things you always need to do. While `try/catch` is certainly nice, you could find that `shell` scripts solve a large(ish) group of problems with a minimum of excess coding. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to know that `[ ... ]` is a command not a syntax element. It is a variant of the `test` command. `[` is the command and `... ]` are arguments passed to it. `]` is supposed to be the last argument.

The problem is that the arguments passed to `[` are parsed by `[` and not by bash and the `if` syntax element will not throw an error on non zero return values of the executed test by it's nature.

The workaround would be to use `[[` (extended test). Bash will check the syntax of arguments passed to `[[`

Further read: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html

Comment: The key is that errors in the condition of an `if` statement are ignored by `set -e`, since it is *expected* that the command may fail.

Comment: No, it is not related to `if`; it is related to `[`. Try `[[`. bash will fail when the syntax is wrong and `set -e` is being used. Btw, `[` is nowadays a bash builtin as `[[` is. I mean bash *could* check the syntax. However it is also still available as a plain command `/bin/[`. I guess bash does not check syntax to keep compatibility with `/bin/[`.

Comment: Because with `[[`, it is an actual syntax error. With `[`, there is no syntax error, just a valid command with a non-zero exit status. Although the *specific* exit code (1 for false expression, 2 for invalid expression) could distinguish between the two cases, `set -e` doesn't know about any particular command's convention. It simply sees the command failed as part of the `if` statement's condition and ignores it.

Comment: Looks like we both mean the same. ;)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see your updated comment until after I posted mine.

Comment: Also, it's likely that it will not be an error with `[[`, since the underlying problem is probably failing to quote a variable expansion.

Comment: I tested my code, and yes, [[ is 'catching' my current issue. All my future bash script  will in extra of the set -e -u -o pipefail -o errtrace, use if with [[... ]]
It seems that [[ ]] has no drawback right?

Comment: The drawback is that it will work only with bash. As long as your *shebang* is `#!/bin/bash` there is no real drawback since bash is installed on almost all Linux systems.